Deploy Power BI Semantic model to different Power BI workspaces
I have a semantic model in a Power BI workspace. I want to deploy this semantic model to 10 different workspaces.
For Each workspace, I want my semantic model to connect to a different database name (But same table name will be present) which is present in SQL server and connect using a gateway.
How can I achieve this from code. Is there a way of writing a script to achieve this?

You can accomplish this via Power BI REST API.

Imports - Post Import In Group
Datasets - Update Datasources In Group

Also see PowerShell Cmdlets

Thank you so much for the response. I have one question. Clone report API will clone the report to target workspace, but the dataset will still remain in the source workspace. I want to copy and duplicate the semantic model into my target workspace and then use the Update data source API to change the data source. Is there a way to clone the Semantic model using REST API similar to Clone Report?

Updated the answer above with a new 1. I admit the name isn't intuitive!
